# skipped 147 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask

I understand the meaning of this error. I found many similar questions here at stackoverflow.com and I have tried to implement the answers those were suggested but still I am getting this error. What I am trying to do is using php web service I am extracting the data from mysql database server and trying to display it in listview using AsyncTask as follows:

```
class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> 
{
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(String... args)
    {
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

        Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());
        try {

                JSONArray  files = json.getJSONArray(TAG_FILES);
                for(int i=0;i<files.length();i++)
                {                     
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    
                    JSONObject e = files.getJSONObject(i);


                    String file_name = e.getString(TAG_FILE_NAME);
                    String sender = e.getString(TAG_SENDER);
                    String subject = e.getString(TAG_SUBJECT);


                    map.put(TAG_SENDER, sender);
                    map.put(TAG_SUBJECT, subject);

                    mylist.add(map);            
                } 


        } catch (JSONException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
        }

        return mylist;

    }
```

This was suggested in many answers that all the processing should be done in doInBackground function. Now below is the code to display this arraylist in ListView

```
 protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) 
    {

        pDialog.dismiss();

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                String[] from = { TAG_SENDER, TAG_SUBJECT };
                int[] to = { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 };


                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(AllProductsActivity.this, mylist,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, from , to);
                      setListAdapter(adapter);

            }
        });

    }
```

Please Help cause first of all I am a beginner of android and I dont have  any clue how to solve this problem . Please check my code and let me know the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This type of error will come if your main thread doing so much work. Basically skip frames will happen maximum time when we test our app in emulator, because its already slow and unable to handle huge operation like a device.

I saw a simple problem in your code. We know onPostExecute() runs on MainThread, But still you use `runOnUiThread(new Runnable()` in onPostExecute() .

You doinbackground method returns an ArrayList , but your onpostexecute hold a string..

Change it as my onPostExecute' parameter that is the ArrayList(mylist)you use in your adapter.

**EDIT**

```
  class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> {

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(String... args){
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet getData = new HttpGet("your_url");
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(getData);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
    String data = "";

    while((data = br.readLine()) != null){
    JsonArray arr = new JsonArray(data);
       for(int i=0;i<arr.length();i++)
            {                     
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    
                JSONObject e = arr.getJSONObject(i);

                String file_name = e.getString(TAG_FILE_NAME);
                String sender = e.getString(TAG_SENDER);
                String subject = e.getString(TAG_SUBJECT);


                map.put(TAG_SENDER, sender);
                map.put(TAG_SUBJECT, subject);

                mylist.add(map);            

    }

    return mylist;

}

 protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist) {
            String[] from = { TAG_SENDER, TAG_SUBJECT };
            int[] to = { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 };


            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(AllProductsActivity.this, mylist,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, from , to);
                  setListAdapter(adapter);

              pDialog.dismiss();

        }
```

Comment: Do you think it might be due to emulator

Comment: may be . but i see there are also some other problems in your code. what is "jParser" ..

Comment: It is one of the java class that i am using in my project. I found this help http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/

Comment: ok. just tell me is your url returns jsonarray. copy and paste the url in your browser and check the returns.

Comment: Yes url is returning jsonarray that i have checked

Comment: Hey One of the error in LogCat is connection to http://127.0.0.1/file.php refused

Comment: this code must work if your url is perfect and returns jsonarray.

Comment: and also add the try catch clause perfectly.i wrote this code roughly here without any editor.

Comment: Yeah Absolutely perfect. now working Thanks a lot mate.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry this is not a super informed answer, but I have 2 suggestions.  First, eliminate the `runOnUiThread` call, because `onPostExecute` already runs on the ui thread (that is the point of the method).  That will not help with any frame skipping, but at least you can get rid of some unneeded code.

Second, create the `ListAdapter` in `doInBackground`.  I doubt it will make much difference, but you might as well get as much off the UI thread as possible.  So, instead of `AsyncTask<String, String, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>` you will use `AsyncTask<String, String, ListAdapter>`.  That leaves only 2 method calls in `onPostExecute`, `pDialog.dismiss` and `setListAdapter`.  You can't get any more efficient than that.  If it still skips frames, I would blame the debugger and move on.

Comment: No sir it aint solving my problem