# How to solve "doing too much work on its main thread service" error in my background Service?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, service

I created a background service for my application but it shows the error "doing too much work on its main thread service". And it is lagging the application to an extend where it is unusable. So, what is the problem with my code?

```
public class TestService extends Service {

    boolean serviceRun = true;
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    Editor editor;
    int serverId;
    int gameId;
    JSONObject jsonObj;
    NotificationManager m_notificationManager;
    int NOTIFICATION_ID = 0;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public class MyBinder extends Binder {
        public TestService getService() {
            return TestService.this;
        }
    }

    private ServiceConnection m_serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
            Service m_service = ((TestService.MyBinder) service).getService();
        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
            Service m_service = null;
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        prefs = getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = prefs.edit();
        serverId = prefs.getInt(Constants.PREF_SERVER_ID, 0);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        final Handler handler = new Handler() {

            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                super.handleMessage(msg);
                if (isNetworkConnected()) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < prefs.getInt(Constants.PREF_FRIEND_COUNT, 0); i++) {
                        if (prefs.getBoolean(Constants.PREF_FRIEND_NOTIFICATION + i, true)) {

                            try {
                                jsonObj = new GetGames().execute(
                                        "apiurl.blabla").get();
                                gameId = jsonObj.getJSONArray(Constants.JSON_GAMES).getJSONObject(0)
                                        .getInt(Constants.JSON_GAME_ID);

                                if (gameId == prefs.getInt(Constants.PREF_LAST_GAME_ID + i, 0)) {

                                } else {

                                    if (!prefs.getBoolean(Constants.PREF_FRIEND_FIRST_TIME + i, false)) {

                                        addNotification(
                                                "Notification", i);
                                        NOTIFICATION_ID++;
                                    } else {
                                        editor.putBoolean(Constants.PREF_FRIEND_FIRST_TIME + i, false);
                                    }

                                    editor.putInt(Constants.PREF_LAST_GAME_ID + i, gameId);
                                    editor.commit();

                                }

                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                    }
                } else {

                }
            }

        };

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(Constants.SERVICE_LOOP_INTERVAL * 1000);
                        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);

                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

            }
        }).start();

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TestService.class);
        bindService(intent, m_serviceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private boolean isNetworkConnected() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        return (cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null);
    }

    private void addNotification(String s, int i) {
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Lol Stalker")
                .setContentText(
                        "Notification text");

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, FriendProfileActivity.class);
        resultIntent.putExtra(Constants.FRIEND_NUMBER, i);
        try {
            resultIntent.putExtra(Constants.JSON, new startFriends().execute(prefs.getInt(Constants.PREF_FRIEND_ID + i, 0))
                    .get());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Because clicking the notification opens a new ("special") activity,
        // there's
        // no need to create an artificial back stack.
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, resultIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        // Sets an ID for the notification
        int mNotificationId = 001;
        // Gets an instance of the NotificationManager service
        NotificationManager mNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // Builds the notification and issues it.
        mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());

    }

    private class startFriends extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String geturl = "apiurl.com";
            HttpGet get = new HttpGet(geturl);
            HttpResponse responseGet = null;
            String response = null;
            try {
                responseGet = client.execute(get);
                HttpEntity resEntityGet = responseGet.getEntity();
                response = EntityUtils.toString(resEntityGet);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

So basicly, what i wanted to craete is to make a background service that ALWAYS runs in the background of device, restart itself when it is executed. That service executes a asynctask that makes http calls every X second if there is network connection, and shows notifications if conditions are met. However it lags too much and makes app impossible to use. How to solve this issue?

Comment: Maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21507967/skipped-147-frames-the-application-may-be-doing-too-much-work-on-its-main-threa) will help?

Comment: Have you considered using alarmmanager ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `.get()` on the execute() of an async task. Because of that it is not async any more. Remove the .get() and place following code lines in onPostExecute of the async task.

Why use a handler as intermediate and an extra async task where you could do all in your thread?

Comment: Alternatively adopt an [Async Callback](https://gist.github.com/ed-george/8097940a2b2a55d036c5) approach

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you are doing the big stuff of your work inside a Handler, and by definition, handleMessage runs on the Main Thread.