# CollapsingToolbarLayout skipped frames for no reason?

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am testing http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html

It is working, but it is stuttering a lot. When checking logCat it says :

```
com.ishan1608.collapsingtoolbartest I/Choreographer: Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

All of my code is here : https://github.com/ishanatmuz/CollapsingToolbarTest

The content that I am displaying only have a large text nothing else. I can't seem to understand the reason for skipped frames.

PLEASE help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678593/the-application-may-be-doing-too-much-work-on-its-main-thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21507967/skipped-147-frames-the-application-may-be-doing-too-much-work-on-its-main-threa

Comment: @Sunny Thank You very much. I figured out the issue after reading the comment http://stackoverflow.com/a/32295725/1641882  Thank You once again. It also solved my age old problem of material design activity transitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the suggestion in the comments by Sunny, I got to take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/32295725/1641882 and found out that the image that I was using was very high resolution, so I reduced the resolution of images and everything became fine.