# Converting image to string using the Base64 algorithm

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to android. I am trying to capture the image and store it in firebase. Since we need to convert the image to string and then store it in firebase, I am using the base64 algorithm.

The methods for capturing image and storing it in the database is :

```
public void capturePhoto(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);

        }
    }

    public void storeDatabase(View v)
    {
        EditText editRollno = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rollno);
        EditText editname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        EditText editmarks = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.marks);
        Firebase ref1 = ref.child("student_information").child("Student" + n);
        ref1.child("Name").setValue(editname.getText().toString());
        ref1.child("Rollno").setValue(editRollno.getText().toString());
        ref1.child("Marks").setValue(editmarks.getText().toString());
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.abc);//your image
        ByteArrayOutputStream bYtE = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bYtE);
        bmp.recycle();
        byte[] byteArray = bYtE.toByteArray();
        imageFile = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
        ref1.child("Image").setValue(imageFile);
        n++;
}
```

When I click on the submit button, it takes a lot of time to upload the values. Moreover, many a times I can see the line

```
Skipped 537 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

in the Android Monitor.

If I comment the image processing lines, it is working all fine.
Can somebody please tell me how to avoid such error so that the image is uploaded instantly in my database.

Comment: If the image size is large then perform this operation in a Background thread. Use an `AsyncTask`.

Comment: The image file size is 1.01 MB

Comment: Yes that is big I guess. You should anyway do a heavy operation like image processing in the background thread. You'll have no problem that way.

Comment: befor you uploading imag you can compress image

Comment: for better compression http://voidcanvas.com/whatsapp-like-image-compression-in-android/

Comment: Submit button? When is storeDatabase() called? storeDatabase takes a file from resource. Not from camera. Why are you converting the resource file to a bitmap first? You can expect memory problems.

Comment: There is a submit button in the layout. On clicking the submit button, storeDatabase() is called.

Comment: So you do not react to all my comments. Any reason?

Comment: are you importing Base64 Class from native android Library or any third party library?? `import android.util.Base64;`

Comment: I wrote import android.until.Base64

Comment: Converting 1MB of data to a different format will take time and thus should not be done on the UI thread. The solution is always the same: do the work off the main thread, for example in an `AsyncTask`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21507967/skipped-147-frames-the-application-may-be-doing-too-much-work-on-its-main-threa

Answer (score 0):

For storing it to the database, I would definitely use `AsyncTask` for this one.  So, what you could have is a separate class that does the following:

```
private class ImageDBManager extends AsyncTask< String, Integer, Void> {
    protected Long doInBackground(String... items) {
     int count = items.length;
     String editRoll = items[0];
     String editName = items[1];
     String editMarks = items[2];
     Firebase ref1 = ref.child("student_information").child("Student" + n);
    ref1.child("Name").setValue(editname.getText().toString());
    ref1.child("Rollno").setValue(editRoll);
    ref1.child("Marks").setValue(editName);
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.abc);//your image
    ByteArrayOutputStream bYtE = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bYtE);
    bmp.recycle();
    byte[] byteArray = bYtE.toByteArray();
    imageFile = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
    ref1.child("Image").setValue(imageFile);
 }

 protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
     setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
 }

 protected void onPostExecute(){

 }
```

}

And then call it like this:

```
public void storeDatabase(View v) {
    ImageDBManager manager = new ImageDBManager();
    EditText editRollno = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rollno);
    EditText editname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    EditText editmarks = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.marks);
    manager.execute(new String[] { editRollno.getText(), editname.getText(), editmarks.getText() }

}
```

If you are capturing the image from the camera, the best reference is here
http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

it's the same idea of starting an activity and implementing `onActivityForResult` where you get the data from the extras in the result, so instead of getting the bitmap from the R.drawable.abc, you'd get it like this in `onActivityForResult`

```
Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
```

Comment: Thanks.. What if the image I need to upload is clicked by the camera? Then, what should I write in place of R.drawable.abc?

Comment: I've updated the answer to include some details in capturing the image